# Pull out Dates from string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to write a regex in Python to pull out '28 june 1994' from the string below and convert june to 6:

```
fur = "missed intake office visit on 28 june 1994 at sierra vista nursing homesuicidal behavior hx of suicidal be"
```

I have tried:

```
fur.extract(r'(?P<day>\d?\d)\s(?P<month>\W+)\s(?P<year>\d+)')
```

june can take multiple forms including: 'jun', 'june', 'june,' 'june;' ect.

Comment: `\W+` will match all non-words characters, I'm sure you meant `\w+?`. Also you want to replace only `june` or other months too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re

fur = "missed intake office visit on 28 june 1994 at sierra vista nursing homesuicidal behavior hx of suicidal be"

data = re.search("(?P<day>\d{1,})\s(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+)\s(?P<year>\d{4})", fur)
print(data.groupdict())
```

Output:

```
{'month': 'june', 'day': '28', 'year': '1994'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(\d{2})[\s]([a-zA-Z]+)[\s](\d{4})
```

This will output of three groups:

**first one:** is the day.

**second one:** is the month name.

**third one:** is the year

output will be:

```
Full match  30-42   `28 june 1994`
Group 1.    30-32   `28`
Group 2.    33-37   `june`
Group 3.    38-42   `1994`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change only June or other monthes too? If U need to change only June, i guess it is enough

```
re.sub("\d{1,}\sjun[\,e\;]?\s\d{4}","6",yourstring)
```

Comment: He said that june can take multiple forms, so it's not a valid option.

Comment: what about this one?

Comment: or this one re.sub("\\b(jun[\,e\;]?)\\b,"6",yourstring)